# HTML Dropdown (select) with Text Wrap and Border after every value (option)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, border

I am trying to achieve two things with DropDown.

- First I want to Wrap the text in the list of options within a dropdown.
- Second, I want to put a border after every option

and I want to support IE (and other browsers too).

This is because I would have long text in the dropdown and I don't wish to cut them. For that reason, I want to do the aforementioned things.

Something like this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/fnagel/GXtpC/embedded/result/

> select the one with "Same with option text formatting, Select an
>   Address". Notice how the options are formatted and have a
>   border-bottom with each of them.

Here is what I tried (Text):-

```css
.myselect {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.myselect option {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100% border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  /* This doesn't work. */
}
```

```html
<select name="d" class="myselect">
  <option value="sdf" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf2" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf3" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf4" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
</select>
```

Comment: this doesn't works in all browsers?? i guess it should work on firefox

Comment: No one of the solutions posted here worked for me :S!

Comment: This problem still has no cross-browser solution in 2021. Looks like browsers retain too much control over the styling of select and option. This is okay by default, but when CSS is specified, it should be supported. Option text can't be wrapped within the option control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

option {
  border: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<select name="d" class="myselect">
  <option value="sdf" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf2" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf3" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf4" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was not able to create multi-lined options in Firefox, based on this solution...

Comment: I am still facing problem, not able to wrap text in dropdown options.

Comment: Doesn't wrap options text. Below answer actually worked.

Comment: Using MS Edge: while the select does show the ellipsis, the options are still showing the whole text on a single line and have no border.

Answer (score 9):

The currently accepted answer only truncates text with ellipsis and adds a border which doesn't completely solve the problem at hand.

I feel like this is a more complete, more cross-browser compatible answer: [Make text in select element wrap when too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018619/make-text-in-select-element-wrap-when-too-long)

In a nutshell, you can either do it the right way by using javascript, or do it the easy... not so compatible way by using the css property `white-space: pre-wrap` on your option elements.

Note: if you go with using `white-space: pre-wrap`, [be sure to add `-moz-` and `-o-` browser prefixes.](http://caniuse.com/#search=white-space)

---

Here's what I've come up with as a quick, simple CSS solution (though the Jquery one I've mentioned is more robust and better):

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* So it doesn't overflow from it's parent */
}

option {
  /* wrap text in compatible browsers */
  -moz-white-space: pre-wrap;
  -o-white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* hide text that can't wrap with an ellipsis */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* add border after every option */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<select name="d" class="myselect">
  <option value="sdf" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf2" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf3" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
  <option value="sdf4" class="test1"> line text How to wrap the big line text </option>
</select>
```

Comment: No way of knowing what the final result looked like originally, but as of today, none of these solutions appear to wrap the text in the select element in Chrome.

Comment: Using MS Edge: the select text is cut off, and the options are still showing the whole text on a single line.