# Fix variant select wrapper width (SqSp)

Tags: css, mobile, wrapper, variant, squarespace

On my individual product pages, there are drop down selection boxes which display the variants for my products. Because some of the variants have longer descriptions, this box becomes longer.
It's fine on the desktop site, but on mobile, the selection bar extends past the edge of the page. This seems to be interfering with a mobile menu I have at the top of the page.

As far as I can tell, i should be targeting 'variant-select-wrapper' but I have looked around a lot can't seem to find a way to shorten this box so that it fits on a mobile display.

Does anyone know a way to effectively shorten or fix the width of this box, or am I targeting the wrong thing?
Thanks

[image: Screenshot of Menu appearance on mobile]

[image: Screenshot of Menu overextension on mobile]

Comment: Could you provide a link the a page with an example?

Comment: @Brandon sure, here's a link to one of the pages with the problem:

https://dani-lane-743w.squarespace.com/seat-covers/ford-courier-seat-covers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS ought to work for you, added to the CSS Editor in Squarespace (or to your CSS files if you're using Dev. Mode).

```
.variant-option select {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will limit the select box width itself so that it does not extend beyond its parent's width. This does not affect the width of the options within the select box, which will continue to extend outside of the parent (and the browser window for that matter) on Windows devices. However, on Android and iOS, the options will appear in a modal-like box, with the options of the text wrapped. This is an acceptable user experience in both cases I think.

To wrap the options on Windows devices, Javascript is needed ([Ref. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018619/make-text-in-select-element-wrap-when-too-long), [Ref. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578388/html-dropdown-select-with-text-wrap-and-border-after-every-value-option)), which is why I think this simple CSS approach is a reasonable compromise.