# wrap text in list generated from jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list which is generated from a database using jquery. The list is a text scring which is too big for one line. I would like to wrap the text to contain it within the div. I have tried word-wrap: break-word and changing the css width on li and div but nothing is working. I am guessing it might be because this text is generated after the DOM has been created with the jquery script.

here is the HTML script

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link  rel="stylesheet" href="month.css">
 <?php $ref = 1;//$_GET['recIndex'];
 ?> 
<script>
 var monthNumber =  "<?php echo $ref;?>";
 function getData(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"getData.php?monthNumber="+monthNumber,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
    var jobs = data[1].jobs;
    var jobTitle = jobs.split(',');
    i = jobTitle.length;
    for (a = 0; a<i; a++){
     var x = jobTitle[a].split(';');
     $('#jobs').append('<option>'+x[0]+'</option>');
     $('#jobslinks').append('<option>'+x[1]+'</option>');
    }
   }
  });
 }
$(document).ready(function(){
 getData();
 if (monthNumber == 1){
  $('h1').text('January');
 }
})
</script>
<body>
<div class='grid-container'>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="mx-auto">
   <span><h1></h1></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div id='jobsTitle'><span>Jobs</span></div>
   <div><ul id='jobs' class='list'></ul></div>
   <div><ul id='jobslinks' class='list'></ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css

```css
body{
 background-color: #D2F9C6;
}
#jobsTitle{
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #7FDE61;
}
.list{
 background-color:white;
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 border: solid;
 border-color: 87C163;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#job{
 width:50%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
#jobslinks{
 width:50%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

this is screen shot of what is happening

[image]

Comment: Your CSS references an element `#job` which doesn't exist in your HTML. Did you mean `#jobs` ?

Comment: yes the #job was a misprint, i have added padding: 10; to both div but this did not change anything

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's frustrating for those who try to help you when the code you post isn't the code you're running.

Comment: Which browser you are using to verify the above code?

Comment: The code I have shown is the coplete code except the PHP script which pulls the data. You can see it working at http://shopping14.ddns.net/allotment/month.php also using google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding an `<option>` element and they will need to be styled..

It should be noted that options are for the `select`, `optgroup` and `datalist`  elements..

As you are nesting them in a `ul`, I would suggest you change the javascript to

```
$('#jobs').append('<li>'+x[0]+'</li>');
$('#jobslinks').append('<li>'+x[1]+'</li>');
```

This will then format correctly the content.

[Related Question & Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024405/1606432)