# Element ui el-select options word wrap

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using element ui's `el-select` tag. And my options inner text is too large. I want to wrap it.

Here is  a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u6b9tye/13/).

And here [an existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018619/make-text-in-select-element-wrap-when-too-long) example.

But I dont want to **ellipsis** the overflowing words. I want to wrap overflowing words to second line. Not only **selects** selected value. All options must **wrap** to second line if overflows. And I want to do it with **pure css** or with vue js methods.  Is there any way for wrapping the words?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the CSS I used to accomplish this:

```css
.el-select-dropdown__item {
  width: 350px;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: unset;
  height: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-top: 10;
  padding-bottom: 10;
}
```