# Text wrap in HTML dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I want to wrap long text in option field.

Example:

```html
<select class="myselect">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>
  <option value="2">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>
  <option value="3">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>

</select>
```

Comment: How we can suggest you while we don't know what is your problem?

Comment: Where's the problem/error?

Comment: He said that he needs to wrap inside text of the `<option>`

Comment: Thanx Mohammad, Sfili_81, SilentCoder, I have just edited my question heading please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Dropdown (select) with Text Wrap and Border after every value (option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578388/html-dropdown-select-with-text-wrap-and-border-after-every-value-option)

Comment: @Abhishek Basically you cannot text wrap in standard select options. Select option tags have limited styling capabilities and it do not support formatting. You can use any jquery widget available out there for select menu to achieve this task.

Comment: @Sfili_81 the dupe does not actually seem to do anything in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code!!Hope This Will Work For You..

```css
.myselect {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
option {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<select class="myselect">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>
  <option value="2">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>
  <option value="3">Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text Dummy textDummy text Dummy text</option>
</select>
```