# how to limit width of Bootstrap select with very long text in options using Jquery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), below the header table I added select inputs ( [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) ).

When I select an option with long text then my table alignment is messed up as you see below :
[image]

when I try table `{ table-layout: fixed; }` then it's fixed but some long data in the body are not displayed properly and overlap the next column

and even setting up `data-width` to `false` in the select wasn't fixing the issue.
Also

```
select option {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden; }
```

Any suggestions please how can I prevent the select box from shrinking when I select an option with long text ?

so basically the `<th>` where I have the select inside should keep the same width as the header when the datatables draw ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var liveBacklogTable = $('#liveBacklogTable').DataTable( {

    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "scroller": true,
    "scrollY": 400,
    "scrollX": "100%",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,

    initComplete: function () { 

     $("select").selectpicker();

     } 
          
} );


} );
```

```css
th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

thead select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    
<table id="liveBacklogTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">

<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>COUNTRY NAME</th>
  <th>COUNTRY CODE</th>
  <th>TERRITORY</th>
  <th>MARKET</th>
  <th>REGION</th>
  <th>Town</th>  
  <th>City</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>STATUS</th>
  <th>Sold To</th>
  <th>Customer Name</th>        
 </tr>
     
 <tr>
  <th>
   <select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body">
     <option value="">Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</option>
     <option value="">Short text</option>
   </select>
   </th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>  
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>
   <th><select class="form-control" title="All" data-container="body"></select></th>        
  </tr>
 </thead>
        
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>  
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>
     <th>test</th>            
   </tr>
 </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Have you used `max-width` before?

Comment: @jbutler483  yes but the problem i have dynamic columns name on the header. it's based on user selection. i can not set fixed max width to each column

Comment: alternatively, remove the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags

Comment: You can place these types of search widgets outside the table - a related/adaptable example is [here](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering).

Comment: Alternatively, do either of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578388/html-dropdown-select-with-text-wrap-and-border-after-every-value-option) provide any help? (May be similar to what you are already using).

Comment: @jbutler483 it's there for a reason to use some datatables callbacks on body and header